# how to print dictionary in django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm working on a translator program. I want the result to appear at the bottom of the original page when I presses the 'submit' button.

There is no error, but there is no change when I press the 'submit' button. I want to show the contents of the dictionary by using table.

This is my codes. 'trans_suc.html', 'views.py' and 'urls.py'.  Please let me know how to modify it.

**trans_sub.html**

```
{% extends 'dialect/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
<!-- template 확장하기 body interface -->
{% block content %}
<!-- Masthead-->

<div class = box>
    <div class = "container">
        <form action="/trans/" method ="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input id = "trans" type ="text" name ="content" placeholder="0/500">
            <input class = "btn" id="trans_btn" type ="submit" value ="번역">
        </form>
        <!--<div><p>{{ content }}</p>-->
            {% for i in context %}
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ i.siteName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ i.contents }}</td>
                    </tr>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**views.py**

```
class Postview(View):

    def get(self, request):
        massage = "hello"
        return render(request, 'dialect/main_page.html',
                      {'msg': massage}
                      )
    @csrf_exempt
    def success(request):
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        context = {
            'content': content
        }

        dict = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\user\\jeju-dialect-translation\\jeju\\dialect\\dict2.csv", sep=",", encoding='cp949')
        
        hannanum = Hannanum()
        okt = Okt()

        nouns = hannanum.nouns(content)

        stem = okt.morphs(content, stem = True)

        tempt=[]

        for i in range(0, len(stem)):
            if (len(stem[i]) == 1):
                tempt.append(stem[i])

        adjective = list(set(stem) - set(tempt))

        results = pd.DataFrame(columns = {'siteName', 'contents'})

        for i in nouns:
            x = dict[dict['siteName'] == i]
            x = x[['siteName', 'contents']]
            results = pd.concat([results, x], axis = 0)

        for i in adjective:
            y = dict[dict['siteName'].str.match(i)]
            results = pd.concat([results, y], axis = 0)

        dropped_duplicates_result = results.drop_duplicates()
        context = dropped_duplicates_result.to_dict()
        
        return render(request, 'dialect/trans_suc.html',
                      context
                      )
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('dialect/', views.Postview.as_view(), name='main_page'),
    path('trans/', views.Postview.success, name='trans_suc'),
    path('dictionary/', views.Postview.dic, name='dictionary')
]
```

Comment: Maybe using Ajax or xmlhttprequest would be better here, then re-rendering the page

Answer (score 0):

if it's normal python dictionary, loop over key and value:

```
{% for key, value in context.items %}
{{ key }}{{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```